# Time-based operation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to perform a time-based operation in MySQL. If the value in the table is 0 while it is 1, the system will start counting time automatically and the value that is 1 should automatically change to 0 at the end of 30 days.

Comment: Please share some code, that you have tried so far.

Comment: Add datetime column into the table structure and save the timestamp when the value was set to 1 or when it must be set backward to 0. Create event procedure which checks this column and reverts it to 0 when the timepoint come. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view for this.  Instead of storing the value, store the timestamp when the timing starts.  Then just use logic to calculate how recent the value is:

```
create view v_mytable as
    select t.*,
           (value_timestamp < curdate() - interval 30 day) as value_flag
    from mytable t;
```